# How do nested namespaces work?

Tags: c++

The `Arguments` class is defined in the `v8::internal` namespace

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/v8/include/v8.h#L113

```
namespace v8 {
// ...
namespace internal {
class Arguments;
}
// ...
}
```

However, it is later used in the `v8` namespace to access it

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/handle_wrap.h#L38

```
using v8::Arguments;
```

Which leads me to to the question "How do nested namespaces work?".

Comment: Maybe the four downvoters would care to elaborate why this is such a horrible question?

Comment: This should not work. Maybe there is a `typedef internal::Arguments Arguments` in the v8 namespace ?

Comment: Class Arguments appears to be defined in namespace v8 (line 1934). It seems the forward declaration is not used for anything (Arguments needn't exist in implementation namespace).

Comment: @bitmask Pre-edit level of English I guess. Most if not all of the downvotes were already there before the edit.

Comment: @Bart: Language proficiency is a very very poor indicator for the general quality of a question. Just my opinion, sorry.

Comment: @bitmask Absolutely. Which is why I'm not one of the downvoters and why I was the one who edited the question. It was merely my guess for a reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They work as you would expect.  Consider that a single-level namespace (e.g. `std::`) is already nested in the global namesapce `::`.  Unless a `using namespace std;` directive is applied, only the `std` name is registered in the global namespace and symbols in `std::` are not directly visible to the global namespace.

Add the second layer and apply the same logic.  Symbols in `v8::internal` are not directly accessible in either the global namespace or `v8::`, but a `using namespace v8;` directive will pull `v8` symbols including `internal::` (the namespace name, not its contents) into the global namespace etc.

As you surely know, there are other ways to pull a single name into another namespace: `using` directives and `typedef` directives.  Unless there is another class named `v8::Arguments`, there is a typedef or using directive pulling `v8::internal::Arguments` into `v8::` as `v8::Arguments`.

---

A quick look at the V8 source code in node.js, there is indeed a class named `v8::Arguments` defined in namespace `v8::` at [line 1946](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/v8/include/v8.h#L1946) and namespace `v8::internal::` is not opened until [line 3709](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/v8/include/v8.h#L3709).

Comment: This does not answer the question. The directive `using v8::Arguments`  does not fit any of the cases you describe.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: It intentionally does not fit the in the described cases.  That's what answers the question, albeit indirectly.  That using directive cannot work unless (a) there is either another class named `v8::Arguments`; or (b) there is another using directive or typedef somewhere to pull `v8::internal::Arguments` into `v8::`.  I'll make this clearer in my answer.